# Filtering array of custom objects with NSPredicate via binding

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, binding, nspredicate

```
class MyClass {
    var result: Bool

    init(result: Bool) {
        self.result = result
     } 
}
```

I have an array(`[MyClass]`) in my `ArrayController` connected via binding and I need to filter this array by property `result`.

For example half of these objects have result as false, I only want to display these items which have `result == true`, but it must be done with NSPredicate and I don't have any clue how to make this predicate, any ideas?

To make it clear, I'm required to use `filterPredicate` variable of `NSArrayController` to filter this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved problem by myself. Here is the code

```
arrayController.filterPredicate = NSPredicate { object, _ in
    (object as? MyClass)?.result
}
```

for dynamic var

```
dynamic var predicate: NSPredicate? = {
    return NSPredicate { object, _ in
        (object as? MyClass)?.result
    }
}()
```

Comment: How is this using the binding?

Comment: Ahh, right, just forgot to paste code for dynamic var.

Comment: What did you bind to what? If you bind the filter predicate of the array controller, you don't have to set it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your class MyClassmust conform to NSObject, 
this turns the declaration into,

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
var result: Bool
init(result: Bool) {
    self.result = result
 } 
}
```

then you can apply the NSPredicate as,

```
let bPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "result contains[cd]       %@", true)
let searchArray = yourArray.filtered(using: bPredicate) as NSArray
```

Comment: As I mention earlier I'm required to use `filterPredicate` of an `NSArrayController`, not creating new array.

Answer (score 1):

User Filter instead of NSPredicate

```
'let filteredArray = yourArray.filter({$0.result == true})'
```